# Android Send Email not present in email client sent

Tags: android, email, android-intent

When I try to send an email (for example with gmail client) via INTENT, in my email client I don't see the email sent. The code is:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
email.setType("application/zip");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(pathZipCryptDestination)));
email.setType("message/rfc822");
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "E-Mail:"));
```

The email arrives but I don't see it in email sent.
I must set some parameter?

Answer (score 0):

What client are you exactly using?

Basically all you do is pass some data to the other app, which uses this. 
It has little to do with your own app, as the other app takes over and completes sending the email. If somehow they do not do this properly and thus your email is not added to your 'send emails' that sounds more like a problem in their app and out of your hands.

Comment: The email client is gmail client (embedded on mobile)

Comment: Should work fine. Are you sure you're not confusing the labels 'send' and 'outbox' ?

Comment: with htc (4.2.2) it works but on my mobile (galaxy s 2.3.6) I don't see the email sent